# How to control DataAnnotations when using Scaffold-DbContext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

This very well could be a duplicate. If so, no problem, but I didn't find exactly what I need.

I'm using this command:

> Scaffold-DbContext "Server=blab blah blah" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir DataModels -DataAnnotations -force

That works, but I'd like some control over which data annotations are created. In particular, every time I have a column that is a `DateTime` I get this:

```
[Column(TypeName = "datetime")]
public DateTime? LastUpdated { get; set; }
```

I don't need this annotation. And in fact, it's causing a problem for me.  The only one I *really* need is: `[Key]`.

I'm sure this is possible, but I am not finding it.

Comment: And in fact, it's causing a problem for me. - what problem exactly??

Comment: @ErikEJ, I am using Dapper.SimpleCrud for data access. I am using your Power Tools plugin (and/or the command line prompt) to just create (reverse engineer) the models from the database. Dapper.SimpleCrud does not seem to recognize or know how to handle that data annotation.

Comment: @ErikEJ: I posted about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65588487/an-object-or-column-name-is-missing-or-empty-for-select-into-statements-verify/65588901#65588901

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but cumbersome, you must implement your own `ICSharpEntityTypeGenerator` and hook that into the Scaffold command via a design time factory.

Alternatively, if I understand your requirement, you would like to avoid all data annotations, except [Key], is that correct? In that case, it may be something I can implement in EF Core Power Tools. Feel free to post a feature request on GitHub.

Comment: An answer from the man himself! I will post that feature request :)

Comment: Can we keep both dataAnnotation and FluentApi?

Comment: No, it is one or the other